# Google Translation doesn't work on HTTPS sites

Tags: web, translation, translate, transliteration

I am using Google Translate on my website. After I updated to HTTPS, Google Translate stopped working. I even used https://www.google.com/jsapi instead of http://www.google.com/jsapi, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is because most of the browsers don’t accept mixed content i.e. calling http resource from HTTPS site.However you can enable it forcefully in your browser.
Using HTTPS for calling jsapi wont be helpful in your case as the real problem occurs when this website internally calls http://www.google.com/inputtools/try/.